# How to hide certain locality labels on a custom Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a custom Google map set up with custom markers for certain points with popup infowindows. I currently have it setup to show all locality labels (eg city/area labels) however the client has asked if we can hide certain localities and not others (so that the relevant areas of interest are always visible but the irrelevant ones are not). You can obviously set it to hide all localities (or other items on the map) but I cannot see anyway of only displaying certain ones? Does anyone know anyway of displaying certain ones and not others?

If this is not possible then presumably the only alternative would be to hide all locality labels and setup 2 different styles of markers, one that is a normal marker withpopup and one that is actually just a text label with no associated popup which can then be used to list the relevant locality labels? Presumably this is possible but is there a better way of doing it as this doesn't seem right?

Thanks so much,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming from your description that you have created a `MapTypeStyle`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyle). And no, there is no easy way, using a Styled Map[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling), to apply a style to specific geographic areas; it just provides the hierarchical model of styling rules.

To answer your specific question about how to create markers that function essentially as labels, the [MarkerWithLabel utility library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerWithLabel) will provide you with a tool that does what you describe. That said, I wouldn't recommend trying to recreate a set of map labels for an area or region using markers; the misgivings you express in your question about this approach are valid.

If you need to implement something along these lines, I suggest taking a look at the following two options and considering if either of these are a good fit for what you are trying to achieve:

1. [Custom Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays)
2. [KML Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)